# in Cypress find total number of elements and log

Tags: cypress

IN `Cypress` how can I find total number of elements which are present in `Listbox`

and How can I log it?

```
cy.get(element)as(alias)

initiacount= cy.get(@alias).length;

cy.log(initialcount)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try the below way.

```
  cy.get('element').then((elem)=>{
      const listingCount = Cypress.$(elem).length;
      console.log("List of Counts:"+listingCount);
       //or 
      cy.log(listingCount);
    })
```

In your case, I assume if that is normal `list box or a drop down box`, may be try the following way:

```
cy.get('select > option').then((option)=>{
          const listingCount = Cypress.$(option).length;
          console.log("List of Counts:"+listingCount);
           //or 
          cy.log(listingCount);
        })
```